# c# web server to receive a file from browser

Tags: c#, webserver

Iam writing a light weight web server in c# using **TcpListener** class. I need to get an image file(jpeg, png) from the browser and store it in the web server directory. I searched over the internet but i couldn't able to get an answer. I can able to send image as response to the client(browser) using **socket.send(byteArray, byteArray.Length, 0)** but i don't know how to receive an image from the client.

Comment: You could take a look at the [Webserver project](http://webserver.codeplex.com/) which I successfully used in my own projects. Maybe enhancing this class instead of writing a new one could be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend.

Here's a simple example, just modify to suit your needs.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server

EDIT: Adding code for writing byte array to file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"MyFile.txt", byteArray);
```

Comment: i have checked the above url but i need to know how to read/receive an binary image stream(jpeg) and store it in a file???

Comment: @selvan You can use: File.WriteAllBytes(@"MyFile.txt", byteArray);